# Incomplete/confusing display of Altair datetime axis when zooming in with selection

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have a timeseries graph defined like this

```py
zoom = alt.selection_interval(bind='scales')
dbm_timeseries = alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_circle()
    .encode(
            y=alt.Y('signal_dbm', title='RSSI (dBm)'),
            x=alt.X("datetime:T", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False), axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-45)),
            color="host:N")
    .add_params(zoom)
    .properties(width=TIMESERIES_WIDTH)
```

where the 'datetime' column in `df` is the appropriate type. I am using a selection instead of interactive to zoom because i am syncing the x-axis across multiple plots but just showing one here.

The problem i have is it comes out like this
[image]

where the seconds are displayed as a kind of addon to the previous tick, which i don't want. This goes away if i zoom out to where only hour and minute resolution are relevant. I have tried using various formatting and time unit options but this ends up removing the nice dynamic scaling that happens when I zoom: having the fully specified year month and day on every tick here is of course a waste of space.

I thought about trying to define by own dynamic formatting based on the selection range but apparently one cannot access the interaction data in python.

Presumably there is some setting i am missing to resolve this and i am hoping someone can point it out - thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to change the format while allowing it to still autoupdate based on zoom level. But you could actually access the interaction data if you use a JupyterChart https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/jupyter_chart.html,